# Why should NumPy be installed via a binary package?

Tags: python, numpy, pip

According to the [NumPy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html):

> In most use cases the best way to install NumPy on your system is by using an installable binary package for your operating system.

But why can't it be installed just as easily using `pip`?

As I understand it, NumPy needs to compile something other than pure Python according to the target machine. How does this work? Does the binary package contain C source files and a C compiler? Or does it contain all the pre-compiled binaries, and just chooses the proper ones to install based on the operating system?

Comment: Why compiling kernel ? Because : some better performance....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pip package just contains the numpy source distribution which includes extensions written in C, so in order to build it you'll need to have a working C compiler (and this certainly doesn't come pre-packaged with the numpy source). You'll also need a LAPACK library which, if you build it from source, will probably also require a FORTRAN 77 compiler.

How easy it is to install numpy via `pip` will depend greatly on what environment you're working in. Generally speaking it's pretty easy to set up the necessary toolchain if you're using Linux or OSX. It's usually Windows users that tend to suffer the most problems, due to the much poorer state of compiler support, so the usual recommendation is to install from a binary distribution. The [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) distribution and [Christoph Gohlke's pre-built binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) are probably the two most popular options.

If you're a Windows user and you're feeling particularly adventurous/masochistic, there are also instructions for compiling numpy and scipy from source [here](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/windows.html).

Comment: So, what the installable binary package do?Just decompress precompiled files?

Comment: For the C extensions, essentially yes (the Python components are distributed as-is). The Anaconda distribution even comes with its own package manager,  `conda`, that also works by fetching Python modules with pre-compiled C extensions etc.

Comment: I don't know if I have got it. As I understand, the installable binary package,such as Anaconda-2.3.0-Windows-x86.exe, contains needed pre-compiled C extensions for all platforms and choose proper ones to install. Is that the case?

Comment: Well, if you download Anaconda-2.3.0-**Windows-x86**.exe, you will get pre-compiled binaries for 32bit Windows. If you download the x86_64 version, you will get binaries for 64bit Windows. There are also 32 and 64bit versions for OSX and Linux available from Continuum's website. It makes much more sense to distribute builds for different platforms separately, rather than bundling everything together into one gigantic installer with binaries for every supported platform.

Comment: If so, whether I can say, a zip formatted installer, such as Anaconda-2.3.0-Windows-x86.zip, is also possible and further, we can just install by **pip install  Anaconda-2.3.0-Windows-x86.zip** in win-32 platform?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Sure, you could compress the `.exe` installer inside a `.zip` archive, but that does not mean that pip will know what to do with it. Just install Anaconda by running the `.exe` file, like you would any other Windows program.

Comment: l mean, we can package all python files and platform-specific c extentions into a single zip file or tar.gz file, then we just unzip these files to finish  installation in corresponding platform . What  I intend to do is installing numpy in an automatic way where a .exe installer is not suitable.

Comment: It might be possible, but you should definitely ask that as a separate question

Comment: Thank you very much.I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

The most important reason is that you need some performant BLAS/LAPACK implementation. There is a lot of options, and if you don't know what you're doing, you're better of when someone chooses that for you.

Intel MKL is one of the better choices, but it's not completely free. Christoph Gohlke's binaries use it. Continuum Analytics is selling [binaries built with MKL](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/mkl-optimizations/) separately.