# What is the usual method for unattended installation of Python packages with platform-specific extensions in Windows?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, package-managers

As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167302/install-numpy-exe-silently-with-batch-file-in-windows) said, there are two obvious options to install NumPy unattended in Windows:

1. Compile numpy and make an msi installer yourself
2. Use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

I think both these methods are overly complicated. As I mentioned in the comments on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138549/why-should-numpy-be-installed-via-a-binary-package), if the Python package is platform-specific, say `win-32`, I'd like to simply *"package all the Python files and platform-specific C extensions into a single `.zip` file or `tar.gz` file, then just unzip these files to finish installation"*, which could be easily done unattended.

I can get the ZIP-format archives for Windows binary distributions of NumPy from [Chris Gohlke's website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) ([a wheel is a ZIP-format archive with a specially formatted filename and the `.whl` extension](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#installing-from-wheels)), and then just install it using:

```
pip install numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

I have tested this in a VirtualBox Win7 environment, and it works.

I just want to know whether this is the usual way to install scientific open-source extension packages (such as scipy, matplotlib and so on) in Windows while unattended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way on Windows is to either download the [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) distribution of Python or download wheels from [Chris Gohlke's website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and then `pip install`ing those wheels.

To add a tiny bit of credibility to my unfounded statements, let me say that [Software Carpentry](https://software-carpentry.org/) uses the Anaconda distribution whenever they are teaching Python to people.  Personally, I use the wheel's from Chris Gohlke's website, because Anaconda is more than I need, and once I have the wheel's they play nicely with virtual environments.

Comment: Thanks for your response. BTW,  does the wheel method suffer any performance loss compared with the standard way, say Anaconda distribution way or official binary installer way, for lack of hardware knowledge, e.g., SSE instructions optimization.